# Does Gmap work with geofield?

Tags: google-maps, location

I know Gmap is designed to work with the location module, but most spatial devs now suggest geofield as the "better" spatial data storage module.

I had to use geofield for an open layers map, and now I want to move away from the location module but I don't want to have to reimplement my other Google maps on the site.

So I can I painlessly switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the simple answer is yes, the Gmap module will work with the Geofield module. What you have to do to get it to work is to add your Geofield field to the view, exclude it from display, and switch the location source in the views Gmap settings from Location to Geofield and then point it to your Geofield field.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should investigate to what extend the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module could help you. Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location).
>
> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).
>
> And the [Set my location](http://regionbound.com/coffee-prices-across-melbourne) block allows your visitors to locate themselves on the map, either automagically --via the Wifi/GPS device on their mobile-- or by typing an address or landmark, like "Eiffel tower" (bottom screenshot, upper left corner, click to enlarge).
>
> Follow this step-by-step tutorial to create a handy [store locator with proximity search, from a list of addresses in a spreadsheet](http://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/drupal-101-mapping-with-leaflet-and-ipgeoloc). You'll learn about the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) modules too!
>
> Finally IPGV&M provides a set of visitor location retrieval technologies, both IP and HTML5-based, so that you can track where past visits came from and where current visitors are located, superimposing their moving positions as markers on your maps.

Its project page contains even more information ...

Comment: any idea for Drupal 8?

Comment: Hey @AdrianCidAlmaguer ... the best I know about the D8 version of this module is what is included in https://www.drupal.org/node/2624188 ... more or less rien, nada ... I'm afraid. Maybe something for YOU to start working on?